# Detecting the translucent regions of a window

Tags: windows, winapi, aero

In Windows 7, we have the glass-like windows where parts of other windows or the desktop shines through:

[image: Translucent Paint.NET window]

Somewhere, Windows must know which regions are translucent in order to render the window correctly.

Many test automation tools have the ability to use bitmaps for comparing expected results and the translucent parts of windows can cause problems.

I wonder whether **it is possible to detect the translucent regions of a window programmatically**, e.g. by an API call, in order to implement a screen comparison tool that is robust against glassy windows.

The usual workaround is to disable Aero, but even then, the window color can depend on other system settings which need to be considered. Detecting the transparent regions could be even more reliable than detecting control panel appearence colors.

Also, since we have semi-automated tests, I'd turn off Aero for a short time only and turn it back on when the automated part of the test is finished. This causes unwanted flickering.

Note that I don't want to detect transparent regions in already captured images as discussed in [Detecting transparent glass in images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573019/detecting-transparent-glass-in-images). I'd like to do it at a time where the OS can still distinguish transparency.

Comment: Just because Windows knows internally where the translucent areas are located does not mean it exposes that information to applications. In any case, what actually happens is that an app creates a window and provides the transparency/translucency information for it, but the actual glass effect is not applied until [DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540.aspx) is compositing the window renderings into an off-screen bitmap that is then rendered onscreen when needed. DWM maintains separate bitmaps for each window, so it can composite them as needed...

Comment: ... If you want to analyze the contents of a window render, try asking the target window to render itself to a bitmap that you provide (see `PrintWindow()`, for instance), then analyze that as needed.  Don't take a screenshot of the screen and try to analyze the target window's portion of that bitmap, since effects have been applied to it. Effects are not applied when a window renders itself to a bitmap, DWM applies effects to the resulting bitmap after the window has finished rendering itself.  So skip the DWM portion and go directly to the window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: thanks, this is exactly the direction I want to go.